# Best way to get the user's IP when the user is using proxy?

Tags: php, security, proxy, ip

As you know, the user's IP is `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`. That's it. But in some situations a server may be behind a proxy *(often a load balancer)*, then IP will be in `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']`. Also [it's recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/how-to-get-the-client-ip-address-in-php#3003233) to store both values.

Ok I've two related questions:

1. `REMOTE_ADDR` is containing what when this `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` isn't empty?
2. What are these things(based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699101/get-the-client-ip-address-using-php#15699240)) ? Might they be containing the IP? If yes then in that case `REMOTE_ADDR` and `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` are containing what?

   - `HTTP_CLIENT_IP`
   - `HTTP_X_FORWARDED`
   - `HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR`
   - `HTTP_FORWARDED`

Comment: `REMOTE_ADDR`'s value varies depending on your server config. Ideally, you'll have something like http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html configured to put the user's real IP in there, but not everyone sets that up right.

Comment: @ceejayoz Are you talking about the configuration of my server or the configuration of the user? If the first one, that means if I config my server correctly, then **always** IP is `REMOTE_ADDR`, right?

Comment: You're mixing things up. If the user is using an outside proxy, that proxy may or may not be sending a forwarded-for header, but you'd want to store the remote addr most likely there anyways. The only time you want to use the forwarded-for header is when it comes from **your** infrastructure, like a load balancer. That's why the Nginx docs include a `set_real_ip_from` example to trust the header only from specific IPs.

Comment: @ceejayoz Alright. I guess this subject is your expertise. Just tell me should I store both `REMOTE_ADDR` and `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` into to separated column, or should I store just one of them, or should I also check the other ones *(`HTTP_CLIENT_IP, ..`)*? Overall how can I store user's IP?

Comment: I store `REMOTE_ADDR`. When I have a load balancer, I use the Nginx RealIP module (Apache has [something similar](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_remoteip.html)) to populate `REMOTE_ADDR` with the load balancer's forwarded-for header. That's it for me.

Comment: @ceejayoz I see, just may you please tell me an example of "load balancer"?

Comment: If you need an example of one, you likely don't have one. I'm not a replacement for Wikipedia.

Comment: @ceejayoz Ah ok, thank you for your attention.

Comment: @ceejayoz Ok just one question, You are constantly saying about just `REMOTE_ADDR` and sometimes `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR`. Well do you think the other cases are useless and I shouldn't care about them? Like `HTTP_CLIENT_IP`, `HTTP_X_FORWARDED`, etc

Comment: I've never seen those in actual usage. If you don't use a load balancer, use `REMOTE_ADDR`. If you use a load balancer, use whatever it uses. In 99% of cases that appears to be `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR`. Stop agonizing over it and just implement what's necessary in your particular setup, *when* it becomes necessary. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445592/what-is-the-difference-between-http-client-ip-and-http-x-forwarded-for

Comment: @ceejayoz Alright .. to be honest, I just don't know how many column should I create in the database for the IP. I don't use any load balancer *(even I don't know what it is)*, So should I just store `REMOTE_ADDR`? And then If I block an IP, and that user uses a proxy *(like HSS)*, he can open my website again? So I'm trying to handle that: **blocking destructive users**.

Comment: Create one column. Store the IP from REMOTE_ADDR there. A user who uses a proxy service like HSS will *not be detectable*. Via any of these techniques. That's one of the main reasons for using those sorts of services - evading bans. It works well.

Comment: (Incidentally, next time, ask the actual question, which would have saved us all this time. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858357/detect-clients-with-proxy-servers-via-php)

Comment: @ceejayoz Really thanks for this link ^ ..! That was exactly what I was looking for. Just what do you mean "it works well" *(in your one before the last comment)*? "it" refers to HSS and you mean HSS makes the user undetectable as well?

Comment: Yes, proxy services work well for users who want to get around an IP ban. There is not much you can do against a determined user.

Comment: @ceejayoz Ah I see. You're one of the super-reputation users which cares about comments and answers them. That's nice of you. Good luck man.